# How to scatter plot for Kmeans and print the outliers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, outliers

I'm working with the Scikit-Learn KMeans model.

This is the code I have implemented, where I have created 3 clusters (0, 1, 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'1.csv',index_col=None)
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data = df)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(dummies)
dummies['cluster_id'] = km.labels_
def distance_to_centroid(row, centroid):
    row = row[['id', 'product', 'store', 'revenue','store_capacity', 'state_AL', 'state_CA', 'state_CH',
       'state_WD', 'country_India', 'country_Japan', 'country_USA']]
    return euclidean(row, centroid)
dummies['distance_to_center0'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[0]),1)

dummies['distance_to_center1'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[1]),1)

dummies['distance_to_center2'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[2]),1)

dummies.head()
```

This is a sample of the data set that I am using:

```
   id,product,store,revenue,store_capacity,state
    1,Ball,AB,222,1000,CA
    1,Pen,AB,234,1452,WD
    2,Books,CD,543,888,MA
    2,Ink,EF,123,9865,NY
```

- How can I create a scatter plot for the clusters?
- How can I get and print the outliers (the points away from the cluster)?

Comment: It is not clear what you're looking for. The number of clusters has nothing to do with the number of axis (i.e. the dimensions) in the plot!

Comment: How can I get and print the outliers (the points away from the cluster)?

Comment: There are many ways to get outliers in general, you have the Histogram, the Boxplot (for each dimension), or you can use many different algorithms to find the outliers in multi-dimensions such as [Mahalanobis Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894355/6365112) or many other examples as in [this very popular Pythonic toolkit](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), then plot the results in 2D or 3D (after using the proper manifold) then change their colors. Nevertheless, there is no guarantee that there will be outliers because you are specifying the number of clusters.

Comment: Moreover, clustering and finding the outliers is a thing, and plotting the results is a another thing. You seem to be confused between these two things. Plots are strictly in 2D or 3D, thus if you have dataset with D>3, then after applying whatever method you want to find the outliers, you choose the dimensions (i.e. the features) you want and plot them (or let a manifold method or PCA chooses them for you), finally you change the colors of the points based on the indices you got from the method applied.

Answer (score 2):

To create a scatter plot for the clusters you just need to color each point by his cluster. Take for example the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns=["A", "B"])
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
df['cluster_id'] = km.labels_
dic = {0:"Blue", 1:"Red", 2:"Green"}
sns.scatterplot(x="A", y="B", data=df, hue="cluster_id", palette = dic)
```

output: (remember it's involve random)

[image]

`hue` divide points by their 'cluster_id' value - in our case, different clusters. `palette` is just to control colors (which was defined in `dic` one line earlier)

Your data consists more then two labels. As you know, we can not plot a 6-dimensional scatter plot.
You can do one of the following:

1. Select only 2 features and show them (feature selection)
2. Reduce dimensions with PCA/TSNE/other algorithm and use new features for scatter (feature extraction)

As for your second question, it depends on how you define "outliers". There is no single definition, and it depends on the case. After running KMeans every point is assigned to a cluster. KMeans does not give you "well, I'm not sure about that point. It's probably an outlier".
Once you decide on a definition for outlier (e.g. "distance from center > 3") you just check if a point is an outlier, and print it.

If I misunderstood any of questions, please clarify. It is better to be more precise about what you're trying to do in order for the community to help you.

Comment: if there are are 3 values [A, B,C] what we have to do?

Comment: you can display in 3D space like in this example: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html or in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285104/3d-scatterplots-in-python-with-hue-colormap-and-legend. Personally I don't think it's helpful to show this in 3D, but the above links will show you how to do so

Comment: can we drew A,B,C columns are there A='red', B='Blue', C='Green' with help of sns

Comment: I don't understand. Columns are axis in our plot, and color is a clustering. If you want A, B, C to be colours, what are the axis in the plot?